# Why does $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$ only yield even permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

$\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\pamat}[1]{\left(\begin{array}{cc} #1 \end{array}\right)}$
In an exercise lesson for Algebra 3, we were proven that the special linear groups over finite fields are all perfect except for $\operatorname{SL}_2(2)$ and $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$. The first of these we were shown to be isomorphic to $S_3$ by permutations of the 1D subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^2$. Working similarly with the other one, which I did myself and was not done in class, or at least not in *that* class, I obtained that a quotient of it is isomorphic to $A_4$. Let me show you how.

First of all, I numbered the lines in $\mathbb{F}_3^2$. I said:
\begin{align*}
1:=\langle(0,1)\rangle, && 2:=\langle(1,2)\rangle, \\
3:=\langle(1,1)\rangle, && 4:=\langle(1,0)\rangle.
\end{align*}
This is well illustrated by the following picture:
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

Notice how strange it seems to call that triangle "line". Yet it is $\langle(1,2)\rangle$.

Secondly, I set out to writing all the elements of $\operatorname{SL}_2(3)$ explicitly. This point and the homomorphism thing below intermingled because the last two matrices I only found after noticing their image was missing from the image of what I had. I won't describe exactly how I found the elements. Here is the group:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{SL}_2(3)={}&\left\{\pamat{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1},\pamat{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2},\pamat{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1},\pamat{2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2},\pamat{1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1},\pamat{2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2},\right. \\
&\left.\pamat{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1},\pamat{2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2},\pamat{1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1},\pamat{2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2},\pamat{1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0},\pamat{2 & 2 \\ 1 & 0},\right. \\
&\left.\pamat{2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0},\pamat{1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0},\pamat{2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1},\pamat{1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2},\pamat{2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1},\pamat{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2},\right. \\
&\left.\pamat{0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2},\pamat{0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1},\pamat{0 & 1 \\ 2 & 2},\pamat{0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1},\pamat{0 & 2 \\ 1 & 0},\pamat{0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Adjacent matrices have the same image under the homomorphism below, since they are obtained one from the other by multiplying by 2 which doesn't alter the image. If I haven't made any mistakes, these are 24 different elements of the group. The group is $\ker\det$ in $\operatorname{GL}_2(3)$. This bigger group has 48 elements, because the first column can be chosen among 8 (that is, 9 in total for the vectors of $\mathbb{F}_3^2$, minus the origin) vectors and the second column must be linearly independent so can be chosen among $|\mathbb{F}_3^2\smallsetminus\langle(\text{first column})\rangle|=9-3=6$ vectors, so $8\cdot6=48$. To get the smaller group we're interested in, we take the kernel of the determinant. The determinant is a homomorphism, so by the [I isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) we have:
$${}^{\operatorname{GL}_2(3)}/_{\operatorname{SL}_2(3)}\cong\mathbb{F}_3^\ast,$$
whereby I mean the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_3$. So:
$$\frac{48}{2}=\frac{|\operatorname{GL}_2(3)|}{|\mathbb{F}_3^\ast|}=|\operatorname{SL}_2(3),$$
which is thus forced to be 24, which implies the above is the full SL group.

If one then does all the calculations necessary, he will find that, seeing SL as acting over the lines numbered above, the matrices map to even permutations. Precisely, if we couple the above matrices by adjacency, we get the images in the following order, assuming the numbering above for the lines:
$$\{id,(1,3,2),(1,2,3),(2,4,3),(2,3,4),(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,3,4),(1,2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}.$$

The map thus constructed is a group homomorphism, and it is surjective. Thus by the I isomorphism theorem we conclude:
$${}^{\operatorname{SL}_2(3)}/_{\ker\phi}\cong A_4,$$
where $\phi$ is the above map, since the above image is evidently the whole of $A_4$. Now this means $\ker\phi$ has 2 elements. Indeed, it is easily shown that $\ker\phi=\langle(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{smallmatrix})\rangle$.

What I was wondering about is: is there any reason the images here are only even permutations whereas in the case of $\operatorname{SL}_2(2)$ they are the whole of $S_3$, or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Only for the field with two elements you have $SL = GL$. What do you get when looking at the action of the full $GL_2(3)$ on the $1$-dimensional subspaces instead? (The [exceptional isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_isomorphism) between alternating/symmetric groups and small matrix groups are probably just coincidences without greater pattern, so I wouldn't hope for a good reason here.)

Comment: ${\rm SL}_2(3)$ has no subgroup of index $2$, so the image of any homomorphism into $S_n$ must lie in $A_n$.